# Avoid losing DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using `ASP.NET Core 2.0` with `EntityFramwork` in conjunction with `DataAnotations`.

When I need to update the models from my DB, I am executing:

```
PM: Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -force
```

**...which removes the DataAnotations from the models.**

I found a workaround by using a `ViewModel` like this:

```
public class Company
    {           
        public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }           
    }

public class VmCompany : Company
    {
        [Required, DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public new string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

In **Create.cshtml.cs** I am binding the ViewModel `VmCompany`:

```
[BindProperty]
public VmCompany VmCompany { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
   ...
}
```

**Create.cshtml** using the ViewModel `VmCompany`

```
  <form method="post">        
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="VmCompany.CompanyId" />        

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="VmCompany.Name">Name</label>
            <input asp-for="VmCompany.Name" class="form-control" />
        </div>            
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="VmCompany.Phone">Phone</label>
            <input asp-for="VmCompany.Phone" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        ...
 <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
</form>
```

**And finally on Page POST:**

I am inserting the data into the Model from the ViewModel

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
            {             
                var company = new Models.Company
                {                                
                    Name = VmCompany.Name,
                    CompanyId = VmCompany.CompanyId,
                    Email =  VmCompany.Email,
                    Phone = VmCompany.Phone,               
                };

                _db.Company.Add(company);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

                return RedirectToPage("/company/list");
            }
```

It works, but is it the right approach? Is there an easier way to keep the model DataAnotations?

Comment: The **correct** approach is **not to use the persistence model as return model to your mvc/webapi**. These two models serve different purposes and if you use the same model your API will always BREAK and add **breaking changes** when you change ANYTHING on your persistence model

Comment: The persistence model defines your **database schema** (when used with relational databases) or just a document structure (when using document databases). Your Models returned from controllers are your **CONTRACTS** with external applications and have completely different requirements, even when the properties and type names match in 95% of the cases

Comment: The **CONTRACTS** have to be stable and not change, since every change to them will break all applications consuming your service, while persistence models can be changed as long as it doesn't affect the contract (i.e. adding an optional or internal field (such as Auditing information you don't want API consumers to see)  or rename a column in the persistence model/database)